# Facebook iOS Error Login Dialog Write privacy is not specified

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login

Has anyone solved this error message when a user is in the login flow?  I tried to toggle my default privacy settings in DevCenter -> Permissions.

I am using the deprecated method in order to both get read and right permissions at the same time.  I have other apps successfully using this method.

```
- (void)openSession
{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email",@"publish_actions",@"user_birthday", nil] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
}];
}
```

[image: Error Image]

Comment: i think you need to set permission in your fbCoding..

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD fbCoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've already replied to your bug report on our developer website(https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/568170979870794).

If you're entering the FacebookDisplayName in your .plist file, it will opt you in for read-write permissions split. What this means is that you can no longer request read/write permissions together(using our deprecated openActiveSessionWithPermissions call). This is not a breaking change but is by design.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, but I didn't see anywhere in the documentation what FacebookDisplayName specifically did when included in the .plist file.  In Fact, I believe the only reference I saw to FacebookDisplayName was that we "must" include it in the .plist file.  We need to include it if we want the new 3.5 feature "Native Login Dialog" right?

Comment: Yes, correct. But Native Login Dialog mandates you to follow our new policy for requesting read and write permissions separately. We will update our docs to specify this more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Set sandbox mode to no in your application settings in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing the newly added FacebookDisplayName property ( as of FB SDK 3.5) from the *.plist file.

Opened a bug @ facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/568170979870794